# SUSY sigma model in QM, bosonic sector?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, path-integral, sigma-models

The bosonic sigma model in ordinary QM (i.e. a 'free' particle trapped on a curved manifold $\mathcal{M}$), has a Hamiltonian which is just the negative Laplacian on $\mathcal{M}$.

For any $\mathcal{M}$ there is a supersymmetric extension where the Hilbert space is extended to the space of differential forms on $\mathcal{M}$ (as opposed to just scalar functions, which are 0-forms), and the Hamiltonian is extended in the natural way to the Laplacian on differential forms (sometimes called the Laplace-de Rham operator).

Crucially, the Hamiltonian acts in the exact same way in the bosonic sector. If a 0-form is an eigenfunction in the bosonic sigma model, it will be an eigenfunction with the exact same eigenvalue in the SUSY sigma model. This should mean that the correlation functions of the bosonic fields which generate these 0-forms are exactly the same in either model.

If this is true, how is this seen in the path integral approach?

In the path integral, the Lagrangian is
$$\frac{1}{2}g_{ab}\dot{\phi}^a\dot{\phi}^b+ig_{ab}\left(\bar\psi^a\dot\psi^b+\Gamma^b_{cd}\bar\psi^a\psi^c\dot{\phi^d}\right)-\frac{1}{2}R_{abcd}\psi^a\bar{\psi}^b\psi^c\bar{\psi}^d.$$
$\phi$ are the bosonic coordinate fields on $\mathcal{M},$ and the geometric quantities $g,\Gamma,R$ all have $\phi$ dependence. If we integrate out the fermionic fields $\psi$ it seems we will get a complicated determinant in terms of $\phi$ and this would modify the correlation functions, which from the canonical quantization point of view we expect to be the same.

Is there any way to see from the path integral alone that these correlation functions are the same?

Comment: Are you positive the bosonic correlation functions are the same? this is not obvious to me, not in the path integral formalism, not in the operator formalism. Is this a well-known property of the system? Do you by any chance have any reference?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, I am positive the energy of the bosonic states is the same in the two systems. This is because the Hamiltonian of the SUSY model is just the Laplace-de Rham operator. The original reference on the QM sigma model which shows this is section 10 of Witten, Nucl Phys B 202 (1982) 253. If the Hamiltonian acting on bosonic states is the same whether there is SUSY or not, then given the correlation functions are just expectation values of the time translations of bosonic fields, they must be the same (unless there is something subtle I am missing).

Comment: Sure the energies are the same, but that does not imply the correlation functions are also the same, does it? E.g., inserting a complete set of eigenstates, you get different answers in the regular theory, and the SUSY one, because the latter contains more states, and I don't expect the extra states to magically add up to zero -- although I definitely could be very wrong here. Witten doesn't say anything about correlators though, as far as I can see. Anyway, best of luck finding the answer!

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, the extra states magically add up to zero because the matrix element of a bosonic field between a fermionic state and the bosonic vacuum is zero

Comment: I find the question confusing... "This should mean that the correlation functions of the bosonic fields which generate these 0-forms are exactly the same in either model" presumably either model refers to SUSY vs nonSUSY QM? If that is the case and the quoted claim is indeed true then it had better follow from a SUSY localisation argument. But prima facie it looks like the 0-form observables aren't BRST closed so it seems you're out of luck

Comment: @alexarvanitakis, if you have time would you mind expanding on what kind of localization argument you mean? I have only seen this used to calculate things like the Witten index, but I am talking about more detailed information about the theory, like correlation functions or at least the spectrum of energy eigenvalues. If you could use some kind of localization argument to show that the fermionic derminant does not depend on $\phi$ that would be great, but I don't see how or why it had better follow from localization.

Comment: You can calculate correlators of invariant observables (under the localising SUSY). Same localisation argument as always: add SUSY exact term to action; assuming your measure is nice, correlators of SUSY invariant operators are invariant under rescaling of the SUSY exact term in the action; take the limit to localise. (Above I referred to the localising supersymmetry as BRST but if that's confusing just ignore that bit of nomenclature)